# how can take value from ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

some of the resign i cant take  value from ajax, where json data is comming like that

[image]
 request

i wan to take value from  ReviewPoint and after that manupulate some other jquery in ajax success block.

but problem is i cant take value when i trying to print value using alert box it showing **"undefine"**

my jquery code is

```
var productid = $("#productid").text();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ProductService/CheckUserExistFirst.asmx/rating',
        method: 'GET',
       // dataType: 'json',       
        data: { productid: productid },
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data.d.ReviewPoint);
            if (data.ReviewPoint < 1) {
                $("#rat-1").removeClass("fa fa-star-o");
                $("#rat-1").addClass("fa fa-star");
            }
            if (data.ReviewPoint < 2) {
                $("#rat-1,#rat-2").removeClass("fa fa-star-o");
                $("#rat-1,#rat-2").addClass("fa fa-star");
            }
            if (data.ReviewPoint < 3) {
                $("#rat-1,#rat-2,#rat-3").removeClass("fa fa-star-o");
                $("#rat-1,#rat-2,#rat-3").addClass("fa fa-star");
            }
            if (data.ReviewPoint < 4) {
                $("#rat-1,#rat-2,#rat-3,#rat-4").removeClass("fa fa-star-o");
                $("#rat-1,#rat-2,#rat-3,#rat-4").addClass("fa fa-star");
            }
            if (data.ReviewPoint < 5) {
                $("#rat-1,#rat-2,#rat-3,#rat-4,#rat-5").removeClass("fa fa-star-o");
                $("#rat-1,#rat-2,#rat-3,#rat-4,#rat-5").addClass("fa fa-star");
            }
        },
        error:function(err){
            alert(err);
    }
    })
```

Comment: `data[0].reivewPoint`

Comment: `alert(data[0].ReviewPoint);`

Comment: You say the alert shows "undefine[d]", but for the ajax response shown, doesn't `alert(data.d.ReviewPoint);` give an error because there is no `d` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is an array so you need to access it by index using array notation. There is also no `d` property in the response. Try this:

```
var reviewPoint = data[0].reviewPoint;
```

Also note that you can DRY up your code by giving all the `#rat-N` elements a common class. You can then use `eq()` and `prevAll()` to set the classes on the required elements. Try this:

```
success: function (data) {
    var reviewPoint = data[0].reviewPoint;

    $('.rat').eq(reviewPoint).prevAll('.rat').addBack().removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
});
```

Comment: He also needs to uncomment `dataType: 'json',`, or to parse it.

Comment: @blex not necessarily. If the response has the `application/json` content-type header (as it should do) then jQuery will automatically deserialise it for you